# How to toggle and zoom in/zoom out on display that shows incoming missiles in Mig-29 Fulcrum (by Novalogic). Screenshot inside

Tags: steam, pc

Here is the image:

[image]

Display that I need is in the right upper corner. How to toggle it on and zoom in/zoom out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn on press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

To zoom in/ zoom out <kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>X</kbd>. Use them inside aircraft (<kbd>F2</kbd>).